# Joomla 3.8.1 - Can't add menu or view Media files

Tags: joomla-3.x, acl

I'm running CentOS 7.4 with PHP 5.4.16 and Server version: 5.6.38 MySQL Community Server (GPL).

I put a fresh installation of Joomla 3.8.1 and I can't add a menu, the menu types it displays in the pop-up dialogue are all blank. When I go to the media to view the graphic files, none of them are shown. Very odd problem. If I right-click and open the media files list in another window, I can then see them. I've tried this on different web browsers and different workstations Mac and Windows, same problem.

I'm just guessing, could this be some sort of ACL thing where it isn't permitting admin to have access? Sounds odd, but I don't know if that could be a problem.

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors (remember to set `Error Reporting` to `Development` and `Debug System` to `yes` in the Global Config) or javascript errors in your browser console?

Comment: I've not used those before, but I have enabled them. The only thing that gets highlighted are in the MySQL database, "NO INDEX KEY COULD BE USED". Any place else to look for errors? Thanks.

Comment: In the JavaScript console I do see this when clicking on the Media to view the logos directory:
Refused to display 'http://myserver/mywebsite/administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=mediaList&tmpl=component&folder=logos' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with Apache's configuration files. The solution was to edit this file:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

and change this line:

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

to this line:

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Then restart the httpd server with these two Linux commands:

```
systemctl stop httpd
systemctl start httpd
```